# View function is not creating view correctly

Tags: python, numpy

I have created numpy array named `a`, then created another array `b` by view of `a`. Ex. `b=a.view()`.

However, `b.base is a` is giving `False` instead of `True`. Please help.

```
a=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

b=a.view()

print(b.base is a) # Expected True, actual was False
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is a view of the original array which is returned by `numpy.arange(6)`

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6)
b = a.reshape(2,3)
c = b.view()
print(c.base is a, b.base is a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will use print statements,You will be very clear about this:-

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
print(a)

b=a.view()
print(b.base)
```

The outputs of the print statements will look like

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
```

You can clearly see the difference.To make the output True you can use this:-

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(6)
newa=a.reshape(2,3)
print(a)
b=newa.view()
print(b.base)
print(b.base is a)
```

The Corresponding output will be:-

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
[0 1 2 3 4 5]
True
```